# Best way of identifying all related objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we used to write stored procedures to parse text and identify all related objects in views. Are there any alternatives or examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a function that you can use to retrieve all object references (currently limited to views)

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html